# how does a c-compiler interpret whitespace in source code?

Tags: c, ascii

Does a c-compiler interpret whitespace in source code somehow else than in a string? I know that a c-compiler interprets whitespace in a string as a ASCI-value.

Comment: Why should it interpret whitespace as anything? It is only required for the compiler to remove any ambiguity. Otherwise, in a string, it is not "whitespace" but a *specific* character, although a function like `isspace()` can categorise it.

Comment: Of course. `int x;` is good. `intx;` is not.

Comment: I suggest you read about compilers [front-end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#Front_end). In brief, multiple white-spaces are ignored. However, they are used to remove ambiguity. `z = x+++y` is it `z = x++ + y` or `z = x + ++y` ?

Comment: @TonyTannous `x+++y` is treated as `x++ +y` because of a rule whose name eludes me. "Least complicated" or something like that, perhaps someone else knows.

Comment: @WeatherVane wasn't aware. Thanks, I will definitely take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Handling of white-space characters is described in clause 5.1.1.2, “Translation phases”, of the 2018 C standard.

In phase 2, each backslash followed by a new-line character is deleted (both the backslash and the new-line).

New-line characters are relevant through phase 4, in which preprocessing  directives are executed. Otherwise, white-space characters outside preprocessor tokens (which include character constants and string literals) serve only to separate preprocessor tokens. In phase 7, they are discarded, or at least become insignificant for purposes of translating the C program.

Comment: It's also worth noting that whitespace is only required to separate *some* tokens. For example, `2+2` and `2 + 2` are equivalent, but `intx;` and `int x`; are not. I think the general rule is that whitespace is required between two tokens if they're both keywords, identifiers, or numeric constants (I could be missing some cases).